# Managing js dependencies

Tags: javascript, dependencies, structure, frontend

We have a site that contains legacy frontend codes. The code is a mess. Different versions of js frameworks or libraries are loaded. Some parts of the codes have head js that handles the dependencies but is not really structured properly. I wanted to refactor this code but I don't really know where to start. Could you suggest any way of handling the restructuring of the codes? Is there any tech out there that could help me handle the js dependencies?

Comment: What kind of dependency manager do you use for the frameworks or libraries you are loading ? As you didn't mentionned it, I suggest you to have a look at npm and bower. You can also use version control with git on each of your own libraries and require them with these dependency managers.

Comment: That is a... big question. I had a to deal with a situation like this on the project I'm currently on, and there's a lot of ways you could go about this. Are there particular technologies that you use already to handle dependencies (e.g. webpack, browserify, RequireJS, etc.), in the project or otherwise? Do you have a build step at all currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first step should be figuring out what third party libraries the project is using. If it hasn't been done already, move your third party libraries into a `vendor/` directory or something similar (and remember to update the URLs accordingly, otherwise everything will break!) Then use a code-searching tool (`git grep` is a good choice if you're using git) to find libraries that are loaded from CDN.

Start a list of all the libraries you're using, the files they're used in, the versions, and their URLs. Depending on the state of your project, this can be A LOT of work, but it's worth it to be able to clearly see all your dependencies.

Once you've done that, you can start making sure everything is getting the same version of the library from the same place.

From there, it's hard to give any useful specific advice since it depends on your project.

Your code searching tool will be your best friend. It can go a long way for making sure you don't break things when you make changes. As I mentioned before, `git grep` is good for git projects. Otherwise, I'd suggest [the_silver_searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) or regular `grep`.

I'd also suggest taking a long hard look at any systems that might already be in place for managing script loading. (That "head js" you mentioned sounds promising.) Even if it's utter garbage and rarely used, you might be able to salvage and improve on it. If it's unsalvageable, it's still something that someone tried to implement in that specific project. Looking at the problems your predecessor ran into will help you avoid running into the same problems as you move forward with a different solution.

(Side note: try not to think of legacy code as garbage. Someone at some point thought it was a good idea. Even if their idea turned out to be awful. you can still get a lot out of seeing where they went wrong and where they went right.)

As long as you're careful, this is all stuff that can make your team's life MUCH easier without impacting how the project actually runs. (Just absolutely make sure to update the URLs of your resources so the scripts still load as you move them around.)

Comment: I'm accepting this one because you've discussed how i'd tackle the situation and gave me some points to keep my eye on and things that could help me in the code reconstruct. Thanks